# How do I solve the INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error?

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am developing an Android application using Android 2.2, my application APK size is 22.5 MB, and I would like to create a new build for a Samsung tablet. I got the following error:

> INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

How do I solve this kind of error?

Comment: were you able to successfully install this application on devices other than the Samsung tablet?

Comment: You need to paste in the logcat output generated when the installation fails.

Comment: I had the same problem on a device I was testing on(HTC Droid Eris). I had a previously installed version of my app on the phone, I just uninstalled and reinstalled and it was fine.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling the app always work. Wipe user data or recreating the AVD are all just doing the same in a more time consuming manner. Question is, Is there a better and quicker option?

Comment: @ChandraMohan that is NOT true. Stop trying to make it true. I've formatted my device and tried to re-install the app. It still throws this error!

Comment: Just change the workspace and should work fine.

Comment: It depends i turn off the eclipse and started it work fine but
You will need to Uninstall your old version and then you should have no more issues... Settings-->Applications-->Manage Applications-->[Find and Uninstall your App] INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT errors should not erupt. Like

Comment: Uninstalling app worked for me

Comment: logcat is your friend here. See my answer below

Comment: This solved my issue !!!

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13556519/2519412

Comment: Clearing space on my Nexus One fixed this issue for me.

Comment: One possible issue could be that your apk is no longer fit to install thus you get this error. Possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530097/installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file-android/60188684#60188684). Solution is to check the apk using apkanalyzer or verify using the program you signed it with. All the best!

Answer (score 117):

This seemed to be related to disk space for me. A newly rolled 5.1 emulator boots with a "low on disk space" error - and looking at the emulator properties, the default space allocated for internal storage is 800MB which seems low.

Solution, therefore was to increase this (I went to 4GB). Oddly the emulator still boots with the same disk space warning but factory resetting it (Settings --> Backup and Restore inside the emulator) solved it entirely for me.

Just a bit odd that it doesn't work out of the box with default settings.

Comment: Indeed this what the issue I had and resetting via the phone settings fixed it for me. thanks!

Comment: Tried almost everything but nothing worked except this one, thanks

Comment: After 2 hrs i found this comment - thank you for saving my day, worked!

Comment: This caused the INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT on my emulator too. I had increased the size but I needed to go to settings and run a factory restore. It fixed the issue.

Comment: Christ... again this happened to me after updating my mac OS. Doubling down on my reimbursement of that solution goto -> settings  and run factory restore.
Had to look up this question just to remember how I fixed it... thank god for history on stack overflow, and I was able to find my comment

Comment: Settings --> Backup and Restore fix it!! Thanks

Comment: Indeed the INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error was removed after factory reset. Notice that APK installs only works from command line, drag & drop still fails for some reason.

Answer (score 116):

Restarting the emulator from the `Android SDK and AVD Manager` and selecting the option `Wipe User Data` has solved this problem for me.

You can find the option as highlighted in the below given image:

[image: Wipe User Data option when starting android emulator]

Comment: What if it's my phone, and not an emulator?

Comment: @mtmurdock try `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` should solve your problem. May be older app exists then uninstall it first.

Comment: @mtmurdock You probably tried, but restarting the phone worked for me :)

Comment: kill server and then start didn't work for me, restarting emulator and Wiping Data works for me actually.

Comment: This worked for me and I had just installed a new emulator.  Very strange

Answer (score 18):

Your old version of the app that you are installing has dependent libraries / jars that have been changed.  I ran into this issue when updating other jar files that my app was refrencing.

You will need to Uninstall your old version and then you should have no more issues...

Settings-->Applications-->Manage Applications-->[Find and Uninstall your App]

INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT errors should not erupt.  Like

```
[2011-06-14 01:23:40 - ProtectYourself] Installing ProtectYourself.apk...
[2011-06-14 01:24:26 - ProtectYourself] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
[2011-06-14 01:24:26 - ProtectYourself] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-06-14 01:24:26 - ProtectYourself] Launch canceled!
```

Whoo hoo.

Comment: I can concur the cause & effect. The same situation happened in my case after tinkering with jars. For me this was on Android 2.3 Gingerbread based devices only, ICS & Lollipop were fine.

Comment: Will this be an issue when uploading to the Play Store? or does the installer delete the app and reinstall?

Answer (score 17):

Ran into this with Android Studio 3.4.1 but using an older (5.0) emulator. [This procedure](https://discuss.appium.io/t/install-failed-dexopt-cant-install-app-on-android-emulator/23965/3) (on Mac) fixed the issue:

1. stop emulator
2. cd ~/.android/avd/[emulator name].avd
3. rm *.lock
4. wipe emulator
5. start emulator

Comment: Doing what's mentioned above *after increasing the emulator's internal storage to 4gb* is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: @dell116 I'm not surprised that sometimes more than one thing will have to be done, just based on all the different answers to this question!

Comment: Agreed! And congrats on snagging the username "Ken".

Comment: Unfortunately none of the combinations of wiping/increasing storage/wiping again helped me. I gave up.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu — I almost gave up, too. I think the emulators must be extremely sensitive and many things can cause them to fail (as evidenced by all the different answers here to a question asked more than eight years ago). Removing the .lock files was key in my case, but I can certainly see where that might not solve all the issues.

Comment: Both `lock` file deletion and `emulator memory increase` were necessary for my case. I increased my Emulator's memory from **1 GB** to **2 GB** and it worked. Only deleting lock file didn't help me.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using **Android Studio**, try clean your project:

Build > Clean Project

Answer (score 11):

It seems like this error message can have many different causes.  The case I came across was on a real device (so the emulator bases solutions did not apply).

Basically, when this happens, set your Logcat filter to **Verbose** or **Warn**, which will help you get more information about the cause.

In my case, multiple or conflicting versions of JUnit were being included in the project I was working on (a large existing codebase). The Android app I was trying to deploy had several library projects as dependencies, and I had mistakenly set things up to include multiple JUnit jar files.

I discovered this based on a series of Logcat messages. Note that the WARN line gives the cause:

```
DEBUG/dalvikvm(4808): DexOpt: 'Ljunit/framework/TestSuite$1;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
11-06 14:30:10.973: WARN/dalvikvm(4808): Invalid file flags in class Ljunit/runner/Sorter$Swapper;: 0209
11-06 14:30:10.973: null/libc(4808): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 4808 (dexopt)
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I agree that you should view LogCat output to see what the actual error message is. I was getting this error and it was because my device was low on storage and it was failing to unzip the APK. I believe there are multiple reasons that this error can be triggered and uninstalling or clearing user data may be unnecessary. I posted this same suggestion as an answer to a similar (duplicate) question.

Comment: SORRY, THIS IS THE SAME POINT THAT Bryan Bedard WAS MAKING. I was out of space -- usually, I get an error like "insufficient space", but for some reason I got this DEXOPT error.  Logcat showed an error Zip inflate: write failed: No space left on device.

Answer (score 11):

I' changed the **RAM size** and internel storage capacity of the emulator **Now IT IS Working...** in eclipse AVD manager

Comment: This also solves the problem in Android Studio. I had only 200Mb internal storage. Rise up to 1GB and problem solved. The same message error... Thanks!!

Comment: Works for me as well. Raise from 200MB!

Answer (score 10):

try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34918549/3737254

if you use android studio 2.0, DISABLE the instant run.

FYI, instant run is new feature from android studio 2.0 (i never used it >.<)

how to disable : preferences -> build, execution & deployment -> instant run -> disable, then works like magic

Enjoy!

Comment: This was my issue when testing old APIs on an emulator.  After changing this and a clean wipe of the emulator it worked!

Answer (score 10):

The only solution that worked for me to fixed this was to increase the VM's RAM to 4GB.

Answer (score 8):

I needed to disable Instant Run to fix the issue. To disable Instant Run on OS X, go to **Android Studio** > **Preferences** > **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Instant Run** then remove the tick from `Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled)`.

Comment: This worked for my `dexopt error.  Application failed to install`.  I tried these before I found this: `adb kill-server` `adb start-server`, restarting Android Studio, and Factory resetting my device.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue today with Android Studio on a new virtual device. It appeared I had downloaded the `x86_64` image, recreating the VD with the equivalent `x86` image fixed it.

I expected to get a `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` in this case but somehow I was stuck with `INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT`

Comment: For me it was the opposite. Attempting to install on `x86` failed. After downloading the image and changing the emulator to `x86_64` the error was gone. I used the API 21 system image.

Comment: The opposite worked for me as well. Tried everything on this thread before trying to use the `x86_64` image instead of the `x86` one. I was also using an API 21 AVD (Nexus 5).

Answer (score 5):

I am working with Android Studio and had the same error.

Deleting the build folder of the main Modul helped. After deleting everything get back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

INSTALL_FAIL_DEXOPT usually has to do with the limit placed on classes.dex. On anything pre-ICS dexopt will fail on anything over 5 MB. Recent versions of Android use an 8 or 16 MB buffer.

Check the size of classes.dex in your APK. It would also be good to see what your method count is, as dex has a 65536 method/field limit.

---

References:

[Error while installing application (INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907346/error-while-installing-application-install-failed-dexopt)

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920

[How to shrink code - 65k method limit in dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471772/how-to-shrink-code-65k-method-limit-in-dex)

Answer (score 4):

verify the storage space on your device

Comment: This helps, I've increased my virtual device's ram and space, then problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem after enabling the **jumboMode** flag in the build (`dex.force.jumbo=true`). Everything worked fine on newer Android devices, but installation failed on Gingerbread.

So if your app requires jumbo mode due to the annoying 65k restriction, try cutting some unused code/strings and setting jumbo mode back to false.

Comment: I also just enabled jumbo mode and started to see this when testing on old devices. Unfortunately reverting back to false didn't resolve the issue for me. Using proguard to shrink the APK did.

Comment: We encountered the same issue, Jumbo Mode is not working with API 10

Answer (score 3):

`classes.dex` does not make it to the final `.apk`. Running `gradlew --offline clean && gradlew --offline assembleDebug` fixed things for me every time. From that point you can start launching the app from Android Studio again.

EDIT: Before what I said above go to Task Manager and kill all `cmd.exe` and `conhost.exe` processes (or just the one in which `aapt` got stuck). Otherwise `aapt` would crash from now on when launched from command line with the infamous error `-1073741819`.

Comment: Appreciated :D worth mentioning that the newest build tools (2.1.1) and gradle plugin (1.0.0-rc1) work like a charm

Comment: Well I don't know about that, I just installed android studio 1.0 and had to do this to get it to work.

Comment: Try killing all java.exe too. How much RAM do you have? Make absolutely sure you have the latest version of the following: Android Studio 1.0.0-rc4, gradle android plugin 1.0.0-rc1, build tools 21.1.1. I haven't seen the error for some time now.

Comment: Build tools are 21.1.1, android studio is 1.0, and I don't know how to find the gradle plugin version. I just downloaded the 1.0 release that appeared yesterday on the android developers site...

Comment: Look in your root project `build.gradle` file. Among buildscript dependencies there should be `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'`.

Comment: It's just 1.0.0. If I try to add -rc4, I get this error: `You must use a newer version of the Android Gradle plugin. The minimum supported version is 1.0.0 and the recommended version is 1.0.0.
Not all versions of the Android Gradle plugin are compatible with all versions of the SDK. If you update your tools, or if you are trying to open a project that was built with an old version of the tools, you may need to update your plugin version number.`

Comment: Rc means Release Candidate. Two days ago was released a full baked version. Just delete the -rc1.

Comment: Meh, I give up. I tried everything short of reinstalling Windows. Maybe I'll try again when Windows 10 launches.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error and fixed it by increasing the size of internal storage.

The internal storage was initially set to 32MB(I know) and then I installed a couple of apks on it, which had left less space  than what was needed for the one to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the app uninstalled and got the INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT error nevertheless.
If you are working with Android Studio / gradle: **gradle clean** did the trick for me,
Cheers.

Comment: I had to use gradlew, but hey it worked! thanks (also removed the package in data/data)

Answer (score 2):

in build.gradle
change  compiled and build to latest version. and it worked for me.

================

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22"
```

Answer (score 2):

I found there's one reason for this problem: not enough space on mobile. So I delete several APP from mobile and it's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

a lot of answers here, but maybe it can help someone
I had this issue with real device and problem was with D8

try to add this to your gradle.properties and it works for me

```
android.enableD8=false
android.enableD8.desugaring= false
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue when trying to install on 2.3 devices (fine on 4.0.3). It ended up being due to a lib project i was using had multiple jars which were for stuff already in android e.g. HttpClient and XML parsers etc. Looking at `logcat` led me to find this as it was telling me it was skipping classes due to them already being present. Nice unhelpful original error there!

Comment: I have the same problem can you explain how did you cleared that issue . I Have libs size more than 7 mb so its not allow me to install in the earlier device like 2.3.

Comment: In my case, I was using gradle build to create apk and the culprit was bouncy-castle provider jar. I had to exclude module 'bcprov-jdk' in root project's compile dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error testing on a real device. Clearing cache/uninstalling, restarting everything didn't work for me, deleting the contents of the build folder did :) (Android studio)

Answer (score 1):

There's no generic solution, you have to find the error reported on your Logcat to be able to figure it out. Sometimes it's a class that can't be 'dexed' due to an usage of a class not available on the specified Target API for instance. Or it could be a class that you're making reference in your code, but the library that it is in is not being packaged.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using proguard to shrink your APK. I have the same issue if I try to install a large 25MB+ APK on an old Samsung Galaxy Ace 2.3.6 device without shrinking/optimizing code with proguard.

Jumbo mode and restarting the device is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was a bug in kotlin plugin, version 1.1.51

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20034

This error appeared on old devices (API 16).

Fixed this by removing @Parcelize annotations and replacing them with this code generator: https://github.com/nekocode/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin-kotlin

Answer (score 1):

targetSdkVersion 22//17==========================> set this number less then or equal to the version of Android OS on devices might help

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "software.nhut.personalutilitiesforlife"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22//17==========================> set this number less then or equal to the version of Android OS on devices might help
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.26"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was happening on some devices running API 21 and 22. Setting `android:vmSafeMode="true"` in manifest under `application` tag resolved the issue. However, it is not recommended for release builds, so I created two xml files in values folder. The default one for older API's:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="vm_safe_mode">true</bool>
</resources>
```

And the same for API's >= 23 with `false` value. In that case devices with newer OS won't be affected and the old ones will at least work.

Comment: Very useful! it is works after add "vmSafeMode=true" to application

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when there were some Unicode characters in my method names (due to, of all things, copy/pasting from a powerpoint file) that Dalvik did not like. You can see this by looking at Logcat output while trying to install the APK.

This was on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by correcting date time on the phone (it was some default date 01.01.1980), and cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed my version of android version 4 support for sdk 21 and had this error. So I went back the version of support for the old version (before 21) and it worked. The error was occurring only in android 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem when I was trying to update new build tools 24.0.1. Internet connection was lost and tools was not downloaded successfully, after that I got this error and spent a lot of time trying to solve it. But when I succesfully updated build tools - problem solved. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the SDK's you need installed and Gradle is targeting the right version.

I was having the same issue, but it was caused by me updating my device to Android 5.0 and then forgetting to change all my builds to target it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue because there was some mismatch with the libraries i was using

**Resolved by updaing android sdk to latest. Check SDK manager if it shows update then fully update, clean your project and then run, it will work :)**

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this will help:**

1. Wipe the user data before launching the emulator
2. clean the project
3. remove dependencies which are not required....

Answer (score 0):

The error get resolved by deleting the build folder of your main app.It will recreate again.

Answer (score 0):

In android Studio click on File -> Invalidate caches/ restart . This did the trick for me when I was getting this error when I got this error on device not emulator.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was proguard that was causing INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT on some Samsung devices with Android 5.x.

Namely I had to add this to proguard - not sure why it helped.

```
-keepattributes LocalVariableTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart your device.

In my case, the app run in most devices except for one: a cellphone that was too old and had been failing lately, the app thrown this error even without having installed the app once.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are using ECLIPSE yet, try clean your project:

Project > Clean...

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that classes.dex is not found in the root of the .apk-package.
Either

- this file is missing in the apk-package or
- it is located in a subfolder within the .apk file.

Both situations cause the termination because Android supposedly searches only in the root of the apk file. The confusion is because the build run of the .apk file was without an error message.

Core reasons for that error may be:

- The dx tool need classes.dex in the current main working folder. But in reality classes.dex is located somewhere other.
- aapt have a wrong information for the location for classes.dex. For example with `aapt.exe add ... bin/classes.dex`. Thats would be wrong because classes.dex is in a subfolder /bin of the created .apk file.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone searching for this with keyword "Room". I met this problem while implementing Room to manage my database. The cause was that I copied all dependencies from Android documentation. Copy only the ones you need. If you are not using Kotlin nor Guava add only:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the follow lines to the gradle.properties file and the problem was solved:

```
android.enableD8=false 
android.enableD8.desugaring= false
```

I'm running the app in a real device.

Answer (score -1):

As this seems to be a problem I have myself encountered multiple times and this time none of the shared solutions helped me, I'll still post what helped me personally and what I believe may help someone else in future:

Go to your project's directory and find build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache file. Remove it - as name suggests, it's a cached dex file that may be outdated if you have made changes to your project's dependencies, build tools version etc.

Answer (score -2):

If you have error INSTALL_FAIL_DEXOPT, see in manifest android:targetSdkVersion. 
Set version < 21
sample:

> android:targetSdkVersion="19"

This worked for me.