# How to install apk with odex to emulator?

Tags: android, apk

I make an apk with odex on Android 4.0. And try to install it to emulator.

```
adb shell install test.apk
```

Get error message is Failure Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT].
Also try to push apk and odex file to /system/app, it not works.
How to install this apk?

Comment: Is your app having linking to some 3rd party library?

Answer (score 0):

```
adb install -r test.apk
```

-r is for reinstallation.

### Update:

If you are now facing [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT] error then you need to uninstall old version of application. There may be a chance that two applications are having same package name, so uninstall the application who is having the same package as your application has.

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. Error message is Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT].

Comment: Create a new AVD and the apk also cannot be installed. Error is  Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT].

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the apk is already installed you have to uninstall the apk using the package name

```
adb uninstall com.sunil// com.sunil is the package name of application
```

To resolve the ODEX issue please wipe your data, start the emulator once again from the Android SDK and AVD Manager by selecting the option Wipe User Data.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-to-solve-install-failed-dexopt-this-error)

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. Error message is Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT].

Comment: Finally, I used a workaround. In makefile ,add LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false, so no odex file is created. Only apk file is created after building.