# Installation failed due to invalid APK file! - Android

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

So there were a couple of posts on this topic, but it looks like my log cat is totally different. Not sure what's going on. When I try to run on my device I get console log:

```
[2012-07-17 14:50:56 - zrox] Uploading zrox.apk onto device '3134F748F94100EC'
[2012-07-17 14:50:56 - zrox] Installing zrox.apk...
[2012-07-17 14:50:57 - zrox] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2012-07-17 14:50:57 - zrox] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-07-17 14:50:57 - zrox] Launch canceled!
```

And Logcat:

```
07-17 19:50:56.043: W/zipro(4533): Unable to open zip '/data/local/tmp/zrox.apk': Permission denied
07-17 19:50:56.043: D/asset(4533): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/zrox.apk'
07-17 19:50:56.047: D/dalvikvm(252): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/zrox.apk
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:722)
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533):  at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:169)
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533):  at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/DefContainer(4533): Failed to parse package
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/ActivityManager(252): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/zrox.apk
07-17 19:50:56.117: D/dalvikvm(252): GC_EXPLICIT freed 380K, 18% free 14176K/17159K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 70ms
```

I just installed a rom on my Nexus S for android 4.1. It worked when I had 4.0.3 yesterday. I do have the 4.1 SDK installed in eclipse, and `android:targetSdkVersion` is set to 16. I have also run a clean on the project. Nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run it in the emulator? What error did you get then?

Comment: Can you install any other APK's?   This sounds like a bug in the rom, saw someone saying something similar yesterday, too.  Silly question would be to see if /data/local/tmp even exists - it should, and be owned by shell, but depending on an upgrade path it might not, since /data/local was used pre-ICS.

Comment: yeah, just checked. It's there. I gave it 777 just in case. still nothing.

Comment: also works fine on the emulator

Comment: can't seem to launch any other APKs from eclipse. :/ was really hoping to develop on a real JB device

Comment: @kousun12 : Probably not the solution but have you made sure you've enabled all of the stuff to allow installing apps from 'unknown' sources (i.e., non Play Store apps)? Also allow USB debugging etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the rom you are running, I'm on a rom ported to the NS4G from Indirect. 
Here are his posts on XDA http://forum.xda-developers.com/search.php?searchid=51245494

I have the same problem as well. :/

Comment: Yeah, it was just a problem with the rom. I installed the OTA JB rom for my Nexus S, and everything's good now.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running latest Siyah Kernel with JB, you can install Extweaks-> Go to Misc Set ADB Binary Mode to DEVELOPMENT ADB ..

Comment: I had the same problem and got it fixed my using the ADB settings you mentioned. So if you are running a Kernel which supports [ExTwaeks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.darekxan.extweaks.app), then @itsmewajid solution will work for you

Comment: Thanks, that saved my day :) Also, fora anyone else having this issue,  it took a reboot after ExTweaks for ADB to work properly.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Mine didn't require a reboot, but it's probably different for various versions of the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pertinent lines:

```
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/zrox.apk
07-17 19:50:56.047: W/PackageParser(4533): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
```

Sounds like the Eclipse is messed up somewhere, try either increasing the memory footprint for the Eclipse.ini file or clean the project and build it again.

I know you may have tried this but its worth a shot!

Checking for updates for Eclipse itself, even the Android Development plugin software for Eclipse is, as of right now, available as version 20.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your AVD and create another one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  There is an accepted answer to this question which has a comment from the OP that confirms that the issue was related to the 'rom'.  It is not clear to me how you answer helps anyone.  Superficially, you seem to be diagnosing a different problem.  When you answer a question like this after a while, it is best to be sure your answer is adding new material.  If you're reasonably convinced that the accepted answer is wrong (despite the accept), then you should say so, explain why, and be able to give useful references to back up your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to permissions. It could not open the archive, so the problem is not inside the manifest file.

So, push it to the device using adb push location, go to the location in the device, change the permission for it to be executable, `chmod 666 name.apk`

then install, pm install name.apk.

Answer (score 0):

It's a ROM/Kernel security problem. With ADBD Insecure you can solve this issue.

[eu.chainfire.adbd - adbd insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd)

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using an emulator, use adb to push the all to your device. This is the same as copying via USB, Bluetooth,  or store to cloud and download using your device. Attempt to install it that way. If it works check your adb tools. If it does not work, then verify your apk using *apksigner* or *jarsigner*. For example;

```
apksigner verify <path to apk>
```

It should give you an idea of what's up. Or use _apkanalyzer to compare the failing apk to a working version. Either way you will start to understand why it is failing!

All my best.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue. It seems eclipse is not changing permissions on the apk. As a workaround you can do the following: use adb push to put your apk on the device then log into the shell and chmod 755 the apk.

Comment: Why would you want to *chmod 755 the apk*? It is not a binary executable. **BUT** what you can do from the `adb shell` is this, `pm install name_of_apk.apk`...