# Android Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOP

Tags: android, installation

I am developing on Android application using Android version from 2.2 to 4.4, my application apk size is 4.25M, it installed successfully and works well in 4.* devices, while it can not successfully installed in Android 2.* device, and I got the error log like this:

```
[2014-09-09 11:07:17 - whatisapp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT. 
[2014-09-09 11:07:17 - whatisapp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-09 11:07:17 - whatisapp] Launch canceled!
```

How to solve this kind of error?

Comment: have you checked the versions in manifest..

Comment: Yes,     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: try to restart adb and re connect your device and check

Comment: I tried, but still not work. Is your skype online? Can i add you as a friend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907346/error-while-installing-application-install-failed-dexopt/15487265#15487265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the reason. the size of *.jar is more than 1.2M, while in lower version device, the DVM may not allow, so the apk can not be installed in my 2.2.2 devices. Delete the jar file and replace with a new smaller one, every thing works well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to remove all jars from app and then again add in lib folder
2. clean your project.
3. Run again.