# trouble writing output: Too many method references: 67245; max is 65536. Solving with Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, dex, android-maven-plugin

I've just reached the dex limit of 65536 methods and I am trying to solve this problem using proguard. Specifically I am trying to understand exactly what it is that Progurard tries to remove.

Does proguard only check for unused classes/methods in my code (that I wrote), or does it go a step further and check my project's dependencies and all the transitive dependencies of those. What if I am only using 1 method from a 10,000 methods jar dependency? Also, if it does remove transitive depenedencies, does it automatically remove all unused transitive dependencies or does it just report back, and I would have to manually exclude them in my pom.xml for example by doing this:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>cn.pedant.sweetalert</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <type>aar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
                <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

if I am not using the appcompat-v7 transitive dependency of the sweetalert dependency.

Finally, while we are at it, is the default proguard config file shipped with android tools ok, or do I need to tweak it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471772/how-to-shrink-code-65k-method-limit-in-dex

Comment: thanks, but not quite what I am looking for. I am trying to understand in depth what proguard is removing and what it isn't