# IncompatibleClassChangeError after updating to Android Build Tools 25.1.6 GCM / FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Since I updated to Android SDK Tools 25.1.6 and Android Support Repository 32.0.0 (this morning), I got the following error, I didn't change anything in my code and it is still working on my colleague computer (Android SDK Tools 25.1.1 + Android Support Repository 30.0.0).

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 
     'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' 
     was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct 
     (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
     at com.xxxxxxx.utils.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:55)
     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is a the piece of code that crash:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this); // <-- crash here
String instanceIDToken = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.google_app_id),
GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

It is when I try to get a token from Google Cloud Messaging.

I'm importing GCM in Gradle with splited play-services :

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0' 
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0' 
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0' 
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.0'
```

**EDIT**
disabling GCM fixed the problem, so my guess is I should migrate to Firebase Cloud Message

**EDIT2**
My device receive Google Play Services 9.0 (yesterday was 8.4.x). Now it doesn't crash anymore, but complain about module descriptor

```
 Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"
 Firebase API initialization failure.
```

Does anyone has a similar error, and how to fix it ?

**FIXED**
special thanks to @stegranet.
`./gradlew -q app:dependencies --configuration compile` helps you to identify what dependencies include SDK 24.x

Main issue is some library import the latest support library using `+` sign instead of a version. This cause the issue, by including the latest available version.

So avoid `+` sign in dependencies ;)

Comment: Apparently Google Cloud Messaging become Firebase Cloud Messaging : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ not sure if it is related, still investigating.

Comment: I feel like this is not a build tools issue. It has to do with google play service. I have been using version 9.0.0 and still get the error plus its complaining about my signature being invalid...

Comment: How do you check the version of Google Play services on your mobile? I see Google Play Music, Games etc but nothing like Play services.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I used the gradle dependency tree to solve this error for me.

Just run `gradle -q app:dependencies --configuration compile`
and check the output for entries like this:

```
+--- com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:+ -> 24.0.0-beta1 (*)
```

As [Diego Giorgini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337203/2080273) said this version is too high (>=24).
So update the dependencies in `build.gradle` like

```
compile('com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4';
}
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
```

Comment: The main issue was some modules import support library using a `+` sign (like in your example). So gradle include the latest version which doesn't fit in out case. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how Android can slip >=24 dependencies into our project if we are specifying everything as below 24. This seems to be a new issue that has now bricked debug versions of my app and led to quite a bit of confusion - whereas the store version with the same code seems fine

Comment: Thanks stegranet for confirming.
We just release an update to fix this. Please try version 9.0.1

Comment: [Android Studio GradleView Plugin](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-view)  to analyze your project.

Comment: where do i run the following code? "gradle -q app:dependencies --configuration compile"

Comment: @Roee run it on the command line in your android studio root project, make sure you have gradle downloaded and added to your environment variables

Answer (score 34):

**update may 27:**

we just released an update (`version 9.0.1`) to fix the incompatibility I mentioned in my first edit.
Please update your dependencies and let us know if this is still an issue.

*Thanks!*

---

**original answer May 20:**

The issue you are experiencing is due to an incompatibility between
`play-services / firebase sdk v9.0.0` and 
`com.android.support:appcompat-v7 >= 24`
(the version released with android-N sdk)

You should be able to fix it by targeting an earlier version of the support library. Like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

Comment: This is the only solution that seems to have worked, thank you. It's a little scary that bugs like that can slip into production releases if you don't mind me saying!

Comment: i did it, updated:- compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2' also com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' but it results into multidex error. Any idea!!

Comment: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2' still has this issue

Comment: Using 9.0.2 for all my 'play-services' modules and 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' in the project build. Also using the  recently released 24.0.0 support library. I was able to remove the error replacing "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'" with "compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'"

Comment: I got this error when trying to change version to 9.0.1
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0. @Diego Giorgini

Answer (score 5):

I've updated the play-services dependencies in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
```

To fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin - I had to update the google-services in the `build.gradle` under the project's root folder

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

You can get the latest update of the google-services [here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/view).

Though its not avoiding the exception but its not crashing the application anymore in my side.

**Update**

I could avoid the crash by updating the Android studio from Beta Channel. Then update your `platform/build-tools` inside SDK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I updated google-services to 3.0.0, but it doesn't help :(

Comment: In my case I'm getting the exception in logcat, but its not crashing anymore

Comment: ok, thanks for you feedback. Are you using Android Build Tools 25.1.6 ?

Comment: you're right, it works with play-services 9.0.0, but not with splited services :(

Comment: i did it, updated      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'

also com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' but it results into multidex error. Any idea!!

Comment: See this answer. This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26724685/3145960

Answer (score 5):

mine worked by with the following:

app level gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
```

root level gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: This worked for me... I changed all versions 24.2.1 to 23.4.0 and getToken works again...  This is terrible! Now I'm scared to upgrade the versions.

Answer (score 4):

Updating to the latest google play services version fixed the issue for me.

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
at the bottom 
    ...

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: thanks.I did update to `9.0.0` too, but still have the issue. I'm currently using splited `gms`. : 
    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.0'`

Comment: I tried to compile with `play-services:9.0.0`,but still the same issue.

Comment: I'm using 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2' but got the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me because of facebook updating it sdk and I had

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

replacing it to

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
```

solved my issuee.

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x

Answer (score 1):

By including all the play services' packages

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
```

you supress the error, but the end result is, that the GCM token retrieval is not working nor we can get an instance of the GCM. So this is not a solution in my books. If anyone has any idea what is going on please enlighten us.

EDIT:

I replaced GCM with firebase, updated android studio from 2.1 to 2.2 to fix the instant run issue with firebase analytics, updated build tools to 24-rc4 and platform tools to 24-rc3, and kept my support libs' version to 23.4.0. Everything seems to be working good now.

Comment: it sounds like we have to implement FCM

Comment: i did it and i still get the same error. I completely removed GCM and replaced it with FCM based on this: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#switch_to_fcm_in_the_app-level_buildgradle Something is wrong with the support library not the GCM or FCM packages

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and reverting from Android Support Repository 32.0.0 to Android Support Repository 31.0.0 solved it.

Comment: how do you revert android support repository ?

Comment: Well the only way that I found is to copy the old repository instead of the new one. The repository is usually under the Android folder that your 'SDK manager' is pointing to (if your using a mac its likely thats this it the path ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras). In the extras folder replace the 'android and 'google' folders with the old ones.

Comment: I found the repo here: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r31.zip, then unzipping that to ../sdk/extras/android and removing the existing m2reposity **seemed** to work so far.

Answer (score 1):

For Android push notification with GCM 2016 :

1) in Android SDK-> SDK Tools check Google Play services

2) in gradle add in dependencies just one line :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
```

(there is no specific classpath and it works for me)

3) you must create 3 class (GCMPushReceiverService, GCMRegistrationIntentService, GCMTokenRefreshListenerService)

4.1) code for GCMTokenRefreshListenerService :

```
package com.myapp.android;

/**
 * Created by skygirl on 02/08/2016.
 */
import android.content.Intent;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService;

public class GCMTokenRefreshListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    //If the token is changed registering the device again
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GCMRegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

4.2) Code for GCMRegistrationIntentService (change authorizedEntity with your project number) :

```
package com.myapp.android;

/**
 * Created by Skygirl on 02/08/2016.
 */
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

public class GCMRegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
    //Constants for success and errors
    public static final String REGISTRATION_SUCCESS = "RegistrationSuccess";
    public static final String REGISTRATION_ERROR = "RegistrationError";

    //Class constructor
    public GCMRegistrationIntentService() {
        super("");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //Registering gcm to the device
        registerGCM();
    }

    private void registerGCM() {
        //Registration complete intent initially null
        Intent registrationComplete = null;

        //Register token is also null
        //we will get the token on successfull registration
        String token = null;
        try {
            //Creating an instanceid
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String authorizedEntity = "XXXXXXXXXX"; //  your project number

            //Getting the token from the instance id
            token = instanceID.getToken(authorizedEntity, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

            //Displaying the token in the log so that we can copy it to send push notification
            //You can also extend the app by storing the token in to your server
            Log.w("GCMRegIntentService", "token:" + token);

            //on registration complete creating intent with success
            registrationComplete = new Intent(REGISTRATION_SUCCESS);

            //Putting the token to the intent
            registrationComplete.putExtra("token", token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //If any error occurred
            Log.w("GCMRegIntentService", "Registration error");
            registrationComplete = new Intent(REGISTRATION_ERROR);
        }

        //Sending the broadcast that registration is completed
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }
}
```

4.3) Code for GCMPushReceiverService :

```
package com.myapp.android;

/**
 * Created by Skygirl on 02/08/2016.
 */
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

//Class is extending GcmListenerService
public class GCMPushReceiverService extends GcmListenerService {

    //This method will be called on every new message received
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        //Getting the message from the bundle
        String message = data.getString("message");
        //Displaying a notiffication with the message
        sendNotification(message);
    }

    //This method is generating a notification and displaying the notification
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        int requestCode = 0;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_logo)
                .setContentTitle("Your Amazing Title")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        noBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build()); //0 = ID of notification
    }
}
```

5) Don't forget to change package name

6) In your mainActivity paste this code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Setup view
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        //When the broadcast received
        //We are sending the broadcast from GCMRegistrationIntentService

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //If the broadcast has received with success
            //that means device is registered successfully
            if(intent.getAction().equals(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS)){
                //Getting the registration token from the intent
                String token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
                //Displaying the token as toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration token:" + token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //if the intent is not with success then displaying error messages
            } else if(intent.getAction().equals(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_ERROR)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GCM registration error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    //Checking play service is available or not
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    //if play service is not available
    if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS != resultCode) {
        //If play service is supported but not installed
        if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            //Displaying message that play service is not installed
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google Play Service is not install/enabled in this device!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(resultCode, getApplicationContext());

            //If play service is not supported
            //Displaying an error message
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This device does not support for Google Play Service!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //If play service is available
    } else {
        //Starting intent to register device
        Intent itent = new Intent(this, GCMRegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(itent);
    }
}

//Unregistering receiver on activity paused
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.w("MainActivity", "onPause");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
}



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
        Log.w("MainActivity", "onResume");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_ERROR));
    }
```

7) In your AndroidManifest.xml add following lines :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

8) in your console logcat copy your token and paste on this [site](https://www.internetfaqs.net/sc/gcm/index.php?success) 
add your project number, your token and a message. It's work fine for me :)

Comment: Hi @Skygirl I'm following your example, any special requirement in the AndroidManifest? Could you please add that part of the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a full day on this, I can confirm 100% that the Optimizely library is also clashing in some way and causing this error. To be specific, I am using Optimizely via Fabric. It is impossible to get Firebase to initialize whilst using Optimizely in this way (maybe in all ways?).

I have posted on their github about it and will contact them directly ...

https://github.com/optimizely/Optimizely-Android-SDK/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I updated SDK tools to 25.1.7 rc1, then the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

updated SDK tools to 25.1.7 and fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am just beginner of using Android.
I wanted to test creating users in `Firebase` following instructions which is provided in the Firebase website.

I added those lines in indicated places.

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
>
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

But createUserWithEmailAndPassword Method kept showing failure in creating users. That's why I visited this question to figure out my problem. I read all and applied each advice. but IT kept showing failure. But When I upgrade `Android Studio from 2.1.1 to 2.1.2`, I could create users successfully.

But when I checked `logcat`, it first showed `"Firebase API initialization failure"` and then showed "FirebaseApp initialization successful".

> ```
> 07-09 18:53:37.012 13352-13352/jayground.firebasetest A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure. How can I solve
> ```
>
> this?
>                                                                            java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
>                                                                                at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
>                                                                                at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5118)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4713)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4596)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zzz
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                at
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5118) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4713) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4596) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>       07-09 18:53:37.022 13352-13352/jayground.firebasetest I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I thought it would be good to share how I solved my problem. (Just I was not sure if I solved it completely. I could create user with com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0 after updating Android Studio version but it still has Firebase API initialization failure in logcat. so I was wondered) I will use 'ASK Question button' next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem, and i change my app gradle version from 1.5.0 to 2.0.0.

change
classpath

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0`

to

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
dependencies {
 compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0`
 compile `com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0`
 compile `com.android.support:design:23.4.0`
 compile `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0`
}
```

Solution 2: detect incompatible on folder .idie/libraries/ 
      .some time you declare play-services-ads:8.4.0 concurrent with play-services-gcm:9.0.0 
      .you must override on build.grade incompatible libraries you detected

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue in release build with message

"The method (com.xx.classname.method) was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type static (declaration of companion object appears in submodule.apk)

The issue was resolved by adding the **proguard rules for okhttp3**