# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when use google play service in my app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I want to use google gcm in my app, but I meet the `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError` when call `XXXFragment.class`, and this problem just happens on android 5.0+(My samsung note3 with cm12-android 5.1). It does not happen in my another phone with android 4.4.4 and an emulator with android 4.4.4. [The answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312340/incompatibleclasschangeerror-after-updating-to-android-build-tools-25-1-6-gcm) point that the version of support v4 is higher than 24 may cause this problem, but this doesn't exist in my project.

Below is the dependencies in `build.gradle`:

`compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }`

So why this happens?

**Update**
This problem does not happens on samsung s6 with android 5.1.1 as well.

Comment: What version of google services are you using?

Comment: @noogui It's the classpath dependencies (`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`) in the `build.gradle` file of my project

Comment: What happens if you change to google-services:2.1.2  ?

Comment: @noogui Thanks, but it not works for me. The app still crash but with another problem `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0011`. This id exists in play-service-base, it is belong to a value named `icon_only`.