# Android: Problems with firebase-auth and appcompat

Tags: android, firebase

I'm integrating **firebase** to my app, but when i go to implement `firebase-auth:9.0.0` i have this error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth implements non-interface class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaja (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth' appears in /data/data/com.viridesoft.kiseichuu/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-auth-9.0.0_9a8a00b0dd4fa0b0760eb2c17842365e25734a0b-classes.dex)
```

I read that this error is caused by the incompatibility between `firebase-auth:9.0.0` and `appcompat-v7:24.1.1`.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Edit: the problem was solved, my problem was the version of the library, i have all 9.4 but auth was 9.0

Comment: Post your module build.gradle file.  Are all the Firebase libraries the same version? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38438897/4815718

Comment: Txs qbix, i read and copy the guide for implement firebase but google put me 9.0 in auth and 9.4 in the others.

Comment: Please post an update if consistent versions of the libraries fixes the problem.

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue with mismatched library versions. Check *all* of your google play services libraries, plugins, and classpaths.

Comment: Please remove `solved` from your title, and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, my problem was the versionS of the libraries, i had all 9.4 but auth was 9.0