# Having Error while exceuting --- InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplication());

Tags: compiler-errors, google-cloud-messaging

This is the error showing  while exceuting InstanceID instanceID;

```
'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
    07-25 15:08:54.919 19852-19874/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[]
                                                       java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                           at nath.prem.com.premgcmproject.GCMRegistrationIntentService.registerGCM(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:60)
                                                           at nath.prem.com.premgcmproject.GCMRegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:41)
                                                           at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
    07-25 15:08:54.961 520-539/? E/AppErrorDialog: Failed to get
```

Comment: This type of error is usually an indication that there is a mismatch between the SDK that is being used and the version of Google Play services that is available on the device. Try updating the Google Play services on the device and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your dependencies in `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

This SO post - [IncompatibleClassChangeError after updating to Android Build Tools 25.1.6 GCM / FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312340/incompatibleclasschangeerror-after-updating-to-android-build-tools-25-1-6-gcm/37337203#37337203) might help you as well.