# Unfortunately Android App stopped

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

```html
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2534(750KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 16% free, 1439KB/1723KB, paused 1.210ms total 209.320ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 48.938ms
W/MainActivity: onResume
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.435ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1004(119KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 41% free, 1448KB/2MB, paused 33.859ms total 111.039ms
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                  [ 09-02 18:38:14.477  2286: 2286 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f5d1785eac0, tid 2286
D/Atlas: Validating map...
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[]
                  Process: com.example.user.gcmexample, PID: 2286
                  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                      at com.example.user.gcmexample.GCMRegistrationIntentService.registerGCM(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:31)
                      at com.example.user.gcmexample.GCMRegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:24)
                      at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f5d1a94d200, error=EGL_SUCCESS
W/MainActivity: onPause
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2286 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

I am working on google cloud messaging with Android. When I am running program, my app not launching and giving error message

> Unfortunately "Application name " has stopped.

Comment: Can u post your gradle.? Check the similar qsn:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312340/incompatibleclasschangeerror-after-updating-to-android-build-tools-25-1-6-gcm

Comment: looks your app consuming much memory, please remove unwanted static variables

Comment: Hi Raghavendra, I went through your given link co-incidentally I got one answer by "skygirl". Same I am using but I am getting problem what is pasted before. Please see and let me know.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0"
}

Comment: My Application working fine, just I changed my sdk version 24 to 23.