# IncompatibleClassChangeError in GCM for Android 24

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-7.0-nougat

### My gradle versions

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 24
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0"
```

Below is my error message,

Caused by:

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/data/com.tcs.fresco.talk.dev/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-gcm-8.3.0_6588f90e2e94e38ac1a1c0e6261e77a2c83f8cc8-classes.dex)
                                                                             at

com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at

com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at

com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at

com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at

com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)

Why this type of error is coming??

Any help will be appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: put your gradle here

Comment: Try and update gcm to the latest version in your `build.gradle` file. Currently I think its `9.4.0`. Also try it with `8.4.0`.

Comment: i am using latest version only but its crashing when i launch the app itself

Comment: at first reformat your question .post total `gradle`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IncompatibleClassChangeError after updating to Android Build Tools 25.1.6 GCM / FCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312340/incompatibleclasschangeerror-after-updating-to-android-build-tools-25-1-6-gcm)

Answer (score 0):

This is a ~ duplicate of:
 [IncompatibleClassChangeError after updating to Android Build Tools 25.1.6 GCM / FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312340/incompatibleclasschangeerror-after-updating-to-android-build-tools-25-1-6-gcm)

**TL;DR:** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0` has the mentioned bug.
Please update to minimum `9.0.1`

You said that your gradle is set to:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0"
```

but you must have some other dependencies that are pulling in the version 9.0.0

Check your dependencies graph with:

```
gradle -q app:dependencies --configuration compile
```