# Error using Push Notification ,java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat Error

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My app.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'android-apt'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.mss.plix"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        //====================Add below two line=============
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
            preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    ext {
        permissionsDispatcherVersion = '2.1.2'
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.4'
        compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.1.3'
        compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.1@aar'
        compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.1.3'
        apt "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.1.3"
        compile project(':library')
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'


    }



    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
```

My Project Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-rc2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Log output when trying to get token

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeC(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.mss.plix.Notifications.GCMRegistrationIntentService.registerGCM(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:43)
                                                          at com.mss.plix.Notifications.GCMRegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:30)
                                                          at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I am implementing Push notification in my app, but when I am calling `GcmIntentService`, I'm getting the error that I have already posted in my log output. I also tried using FCM but getting the same issue. If anyone has implemented this, then please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37312340/4815718 ?  The problem may be related to incompatible versions of the libraries.  One answer at the linked question was to upgrade to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1`.  Also, you will be better build performance and smaller APK if you only include the Play Services and Firebase libraries you actually need.  Including `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.x.x.` adds them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**> Got Answer of my question the error is because of using play service

> 9.0.0
>
> But when we update the play service to 9.4.0 and same as firebase
>   dependency .and the main issue in my gradle is   apply plugin:
>   'com.google.gms.google-services' will not come at the top of gradle it
>   will come at the bottom after dependency .And i dont know why this
>   works fine and my token and context compact issue also got resolved.**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'android-apt'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.mss.plix"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        //====================Add below two line=============
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
            preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    ext {
        permissionsDispatcherVersion = '2.1.2'
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.4'
        compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.1.3'
        compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.1@aar'
        compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.1.3'
        apt "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.1.3"
        compile project(':library')
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'


    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
```

it should be like this . :)