# Getting an error after initial Firebase setup

Tags: android, firebase

I have followed Firebase quick start guide to complete initial setup of Firebase. I haven't used any of it's classes yet , just done basic setup for later use. But now I get an error in logcat. Note that the error doesn't cause a crash ( yet , dunno)

Here is the error:

> Task exception on worker thread:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)'
>   was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type
>   direct (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in
>   /data/data/myPackageName/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-iid-9.0.0_some-ID-which-I-think-shouldn't-be-exposed-here-classes.dex):
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)

So what is this error about? Should I just ignore it and keep going?

Comment: See this related question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37312340/4815718

Answer (score 0):

Just use `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'`  instead of  `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'` in your gradle file.
In my case works without erros.