# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError causes app to crash, using Firebase and Google Play Services

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-analytics

I'm receiving following crash log when I run my app with firebase and google play services

**Exception in Emulator:**

```
11-10 17:14:39.716 2645-2645/com.winjit.musiclib.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.winjit.musiclib.sample, PID: 2645
  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.winjit.musiclib.sample-1/base.apk)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zziB(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzA(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Exception in Device:**

```
11-10 17:30:50.724 9161-9161/com.winjit.musiclib.sample E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1801)
       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1776)
       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5464)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5037)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4977)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1562)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.winjit.musiclib.sample-1/base.apk)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source) 
       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1801) 
       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1776) 
       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5464) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5037) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4977) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1562) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681) 
11-10 17:30:50.866 9161-9195/com.winjit.musiclib.sample E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.winjit.musiclib.sample-1/base.apk): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
```

Below is my gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IncompatibleClassChangeError after updating to Android Build Tools 25.1.6 GCM / FCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312340/incompatibleclasschangeerror-after-updating-to-android-build-tools-25-1-6-gcm)

Answer (score 0):

Try to  compile

```
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
```

instead of

```
      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
```

Also update to the latest google-play-services and google repository through the SDK Manager:

[image]

Try to use this solution. I had solved problem using above solution. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: i need to use firebase analytics and amdob ads in this app