# Installation failed on Android Gingerbread and Froyo - INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: java, android, dalvik

When I try to install my apk file on devices running Gingerbread and Froyo it throws this error:
Application couldn't be installed: pkg: /sdcard/temp.apk Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]. If someone installs it through Google Play it shows a popup with the following message: "Package File Invalid".
I contacted Google Play Developer Support and they advised me to do a search for 'dexopt failed gingerbread froyo' on android dev forums and I did search for this issue but could't find any solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Does this error help?
DexInv: --- END '/mnt/asec/org.example.android-1/pkg.apk' --- status=0x000b, process failed
dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/mnt@asec@org.example.android-1@pkg.apk@classes.dex' res = 11

Comment: I searched and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-to-solve-install-failed-dexopt-this-error

Comment: Well yeah, but I can't go to every user that is using the app from Google Play and check each phone individually. Is there a way to do this in code so the users don't face such problem.

Comment: The "status=0x000b" means the process terminated with signal 11 (segmentation fault).  In other words, it crashed.