# Failure INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT for Android wear emulator

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

> adb -s emulator-5556 install
>   S:\AS\MyWatch\wear\build\outputs\apk\wear-debug.apk
>   S:\AS\MyWatch\wear\build\outputs\apk\wear-debug.apk: 1 file pushed.
>   0.5 MB/s (1883889 bytes in 3.409s)
>           pkg: /data/local/tmp/wear-debug.apk Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

While installing on new fresh wear emulator I see this log. On a real device all works fine. What the hell is this? The emulator is connected. I just want to test UI.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.2'
}
```

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-to-solve-install-failed-dexopt-this-error/41722043) dealth with the same error. Maybe it can help.

Comment: @noogui , nice idea. But I've already removed this device. Nethertheless, 10x