# com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Tags: react-native

i am getting the error while running my app in android emulator

com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT

Comment: You might search a bit. There are some common reasons for that error, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-do-i-solve-the-install-failed-dexopt-error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By cleaning cache and making more space in android emulator helped me to resolve it.

Answer (score 21):

You probably need to allocate more internal memory to your emulator. This can be done by:

1. Opening Android Virtual Device Manager...
2. Edit the device you're having a problem with.

[image]
3. Show Advanced Settings (see yellow arrows below)

[image]

4. Increase the internal storage to 5120MB

[image]

5. Restart the emulator (cold boot)

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall the existing app with the same package name(google service file with the same package) from the phone. Hope this helps someone.